# Apply math to a member of a list in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to keep track of some numbers in a list, but I am unable to edit members of said list. When I try subtracting from it I am given the error "unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'int'"

```
with open("prices.txt") as f:
        seatCapacity = []
        for line in f: 
            line = [int(i) for i in line[10:].split()]
            seatCapacity.append(line)

seatCapacity[seat] -= 1
```

seatCapacity[seat] displays a number correctly so I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong.

Edit:
Some examples of output are

```
print(seatCapacity)
```

output:

```
[[150], [120], [200], [80], [120], [80]]
```

and

```
print(seatCapacity[seat])
```

output:

```
[150]
```

Comment: What's your error message? Show the value of `seatCapacity[seat]` (it's obviously a list).  `seat` itself isn't defined in your example, nor is there an example of `prices.txt`.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, seat is a number from another function 0-5, outputs it gives are [[150], [120], [200], [80], [120], [80]]. The error it gives when I try to do the math is "unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'int'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> seatCapacity[seat] displays a number correctly so I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong.

Actually, not according to the output you posted. If it's correct that `print(seatCapacity[seat])` displays `[150]`, then `seatCapacity[seat]` is in fact a list. Note the brackets that make the difference between `[150]`, which represents a list, and `150`, which represents an integer.

The reason this is happening is that you set `line` to a list during your loop.

```
line = [int(i) for i in line[10:].split()]
```

What this does is take the current line of the file, for example

```
"something 10 20 30 40"
```

strips off the first 10 characters

```
"10 20 30 40"
```

splits it into a list of individual whitespace-separated pieces

```
["10", "20", "30", "40"]
```

then iterates over each of those pieces (`i`) and converts it to an integer (`int(i)`), recombining the results into a list.

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

That list is what gets appended to `seatCapacity` in the next line.

If you want to append an integer, instead of a list, you would have to do something to get the integer you want out of that list. For example, use `list[0]` if you always want the first thing in the list, or `list[-1]` if you always want the last one. Or, if you know that there will always be one number on each line (not counting the first 10 characters), you can just convert that string to a line directly, using something like `int(line[10:].strip())`. (`strip()` removes whitespace from the beginning and end. It may be optional depending on the content of your file.)

Answer (score 1):

`seatCapacity` is a list of lists, because `line` is a list - see the first line after the for loop begins:

```
 line = [int(i) for i in line[10:].split()]
```

Depending on the contents of `prices.txt`, you might be able to fix this problem by removing the brackets on that line.

Comment: I'm not sure which brackets you're referring to, prices.txt is lines of csv and removing the brackets from the line you listed gives another error. I'm also not sure how line became a list.

Comment: The brackets are `[` and `]` - they are how you define a list in Python. `seatCapacity = []` creates an empty list. If `line[10:].split()` contains more than one number, you could use a second for loop to append each individual number to `seatCapacity`.